# Customer/donor total paid report

Tags: gnucash

Using GnuCash for a non-profit and am categorizing my donors as customers and entering their pledges as invoices.

Now they make big pledges and pay over some payment period, I would like to be able to run a report to see the amount paid so far by donor for appreciation etc.

The **Reports > Business > Customer Summary** shows the total amount invoiced (accounts receivable) I can't seem to find a way to only include the amount paid.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around for a solution I scripted up the following using [piecash](https://piecash.readthedocs.io/)

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
from functools import partial

import piecash

book = piecash.open_book('business.gnucash', readonly=True)

ar = [account for account in book.accounts if account.type == 'RECEIVABLE'][0]

customers = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, Decimal))

for split in ar.splits:
    if split.action in ['Invoice', 'Payment'] and split.transaction.post_date <= datetime.now().date():
        customers[split.transaction.description][split.action] += split.quantity

with open('customer-report.csv', 'w', newline=None) as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['customer', 'invoiced', 'paid'])

    writer.writerows([customer, totals['Invoice'], totals['Payment'] * -1]
                     for customer, totals in customers.items())
```

While it might do the job, I am not happy relying on it because:

1. I don't know how smart it is to rely on the transaction description being the customer name
2. The project is [recently unmaintained](https://github.com/sdementen/piecash/issues/215#issuecomment-1793497726)...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look at the GnuCash **Receipt** report (*Reports > Business > Receipt*)

This report lists all of the *payments* that have been recorded against an *invoice*, as well as listing the amount remaining unpaid from the original *Invoice Amount*.

Please note that the report lists payments *made against an invoice* rather than payments *made by a customer/donor* - but if you only issue one invoice to record a donor's pledge in each reporting period, that one invoice may effectively represent the one donor's commitment.

The screenshot below shows that two payments have so far been recorded against *Donor1*'s pledge of $10,000.  A further $7,000 is still expected in future donations.

[image]

If you need to report fairly regularly on contributions by particular donors, you can "Save As" the report options several times so that reports of contributions by those donors can be easily run with only a couple of clicks.

Comment: Thanks, while it can do the job, I will need to run this for each donor and each receipt...